# Nodejs - How to export * from "module"

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to do an `export * from "module"` in a NodeJS environment that doesn't use ES6 imports?

Do I have to do:

```
const {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ..., z} = require("module");
module.exports = {a, b, c, d, ..., z};
```

or is there any other faster way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module.exports = require("module");
```

Comment: and will I be able to access the atoms and not a molecule? I mean, I want to do const {g, z} = require("the-other-module");  not to do const otherModule = require("the-other-module"); otherModule.z();

Comment: Your follow-up question is unclear. Never heard of atoms/molecules in this context. Why don't you try it out?